# Given an array of random values, calculate which values are missing and how many of them are there?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been doing some CodeSignal projects and recently came across a problem that gives you a random array of numbers and requires you to return the quantity of numbers needed to make the array consecutive.

For example, if you're given an array of [3, 6, 8], you'll need '4', '5', and '7' to make the array consecutive. So the output should be '3'.

I've found an answer that works:

```
return Math.max.apply(Math, arr) - Math.min.apply(Math, arr) - 
arr.length + 1;
```

The problem is that I'm not sure why this works. Is there a mathematical concept that explains why subtracting the min value and length of an array from the max value gives you the correct answer?

- All numbers are integers
- Not sorted

Comment: you need all numbers MIN to MAX. You have length numbers of those. How many do you still need?

Comment: first, is the random array, sorted?

Comment: are the numbers always integers, or they can be float as well? there are many ideas you should clarify before asking this type of question...

Comment: The array is random, my apologies

Comment: And they're always integers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the array is has only integers and that the number are sorted, then you can do like this:

```
const arr = [1, 4, 6, 9];

let count = 0;
for(let i = arr[0]; i < arr[arr.length-1]; ++i) {
  if(!arr.includes(i)) {
    count++;
  }
}

// 5
console.log(count);
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/xuvikotoju/edit?html,js,console,output

And yes, if you have a sorted array you can apply a formula as you did and  as was mentioned in the comments:

`(max - min) - (array.length + 1)` and you'll have the same answer.
with O(1) performance

Answer (score 0):

The formula you showed assumes that there are no duplicates in the input array.

It starts by subtracting the minimum element from the maximum element. If there are no missing numbers, the length of the array is the same as this difference plus 1. For instance, if the array contains `1` to `10`, the difference is `10-1 = 9`, and the length of the array is `10`. You should easily be able to convince yourself that this is true for any minimum and maximum element.

Each missing element in the sequence decreases the length of the array by 1. So if you subtract the actual length of the array from the length that it would be if there were nothing missing, you get the number that are missing.

Thus:

```
missing = max - min + 1 - length
```